# Is √n^x irrational, if x is an odd integer?

Tags: radicals

I am assuming that, n is a prime number, because you can express composite numbers to prime by enlarging the exponent.
a = n*n^x-1 = n

I don't know how to prove or disprove it, but if x is odd then,

a is always multiplied by a prime number, which square rooted are irrational.

For example n=5; x=11

√5^11 = √5^10*5 = 5^5√5
The prime number is left in the sqrt.
Is my hint correct? I don't think it completely proves this theory.

If x is even, then halving the exponent is good enough.

N and x values are acceptable as disproving.
Thanks.

Comment: Please use MathJax when formatting your question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: How about $4^3$?  Statement is true if $n$ is a square free number.